# Error: “ File ended while scanning use of \__um_group_end:n.”

Tags: xetex

Yesterday I typed the command `\mathcal{C)` and got this error

File ended while scanning use of __um_group_end:n.

This is the first time I get this error and I don’t know where it comes from. Could someone explain the error ?

**Edit:** Added MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacklozenge$}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{makecell}

%ability to add num of pages automatically
\usepackage{zref-totpages}

%diagonal lines in cell tables
%\usepackage{slashbox} (deprecated since 1993)
\usepackage{diagbox}

%initiate epigraph 
\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.8\textwidth}
\setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}

%set ocre
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}

%asana math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Asana Math}

%style of enumeration item

\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes,snakes,arrows,intersections, backgrounds,calc, trees, hobby,decorations.pathmorphing ,  patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,svg.path,shapes.geometric,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% we want to letterspace uppercased words and those in small caps, so:
\usepackage{microtype}


\begin{document}
    
    $\mathcal{C)$
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in, let's say, a minimal compilable example? You know the drill

Comment: @DG' added an MWE per request. I was on mobile yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `\mathcal{C)`, i.e. opening `{` is never closed, there is incompatible `)`. Unfortunatelly, LaTeX defines the `\mathcal` macro in such sense that the bug report isn't about the `\mathcal` macro itself.

Comment: Yeah, the error does not reveal the culprit immediately. It's so vague. I had to search for a while to find it.